# How to append data to end of rows in csv(PHP)

Tags: php, csv

Hey I'm having some trouble trying to append to data to the end of a row of a csv I have created. To simplify it, I have a csv with some data and another csv with some data. I've open one to read, to get the data i want, then i open the target file with append, but i can't get it to go to the row where the dates match. Hopefully my code will clarify anything that's unclear:

```
   foreach($gFiles as $gFile)
{

if($i<count($gFiles))
    {
preg_match("/^.*-([0-9]{8})/", $gFile, $dates);
$fdate = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('Ymd', $dates[1]);
$fdate = $fdate->format('Y-m-d');
$fdate = strtotime($fdate);
$targetDate = strtotime($matches[1]);
$i++;
$diff = abs($targetDate - $fdate);$transdates[] = $diff;
 } 

 $minimal = min($transdates);
 if(abs($targetDate - $fdate) == $minimal)
 {
    $closest = date("Y-m-d", $fdate);

    if(($handle2 = fopen($gFile, "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($data2 = fgetcsv($handle2, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {

                if($data2[0] != preg_match("/^([0-9]{8})/", $gFile))
                {
                    $dt2 = $data2[0];
                    $dt2 = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('Ymd', $data2[0]);
                    $dt2= $dt2->format('Y-m-d');

                foreach($originaldates as $odate)
                {   

            if($odate == $dt2)
            {
            echo $dt2;
        $update = fopen($db_file, 'a');
        fputcsv($update, [$data2[2], $data2[3], $data2[4]]);



            }else if ($odate != $dt2)
            {
                continue ;
            }


                   }
                }

            }
        }
    }
 }
    fclose($update);
    fclose($handle2);
```

If you're wondering about the dates, those are for date comparisons but as you can tell, i transform them back to dates after determining which date is the closest to a specified file. This code currently appends to the file but adds 4 new rows instead of adding the 4 rows to the appropriate areas where the dates match. Any help would be appreciated. Also don't stress if the closing bracketts don't match everything because there's a lot of code prior to this as well but shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Your description of the problem you are trying to solve isn't clear. Are you trying to append rows to an existing CSV or are you trying to update rows within an existing CSV? Very big difference, obviously, and the approach to them is very different.

Comment: Sorry about not being clear. I'm trying to Update rows within an existing CSV.  i.e
data1 data 2 data3 data4  data5 --->  data1 data2 data3 data4 data5
aaa    bbb     cccc    null     null   ----> aaa    bbb    cccc    dddd  eeee